# Dynamic memory allocation for char**

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, c-strings, calloc

I'm trying to dynamically allocate memory for an array of strings, but I'm suffering a segmentation fault. If you can show me some ways to do it, that would be really helpful.

My knowledge so far is that char* is a string, and char** is a two-dimensional array of strings.
If s[i] is a string, shouldn't *(s + i) also be the same thing? I am confused about the topic.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;

int main(void)
{
    scanf("%i", &n);  //number of strings being inputted

    char **s = calloc(n, 10 * (sizeof(char) + 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //get strings
    {
        fgets(*(s + i), 10 * (sizeof(char) + 1), stdin);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //print the strings
    {
        fputs(*(s + i), stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this declaration

```
char **s = calloc(n, 10 * (sizeof(char) + 1));
```

you allocated a memory the address of which is assigned to the pointer `s`. The memory was zero-initialized due to calling the function `calloc`.

So in this statement

```
fgets(*(s + i), 10 * (sizeof(char) + 1), stdin);
```

the pointer `s` is dereferenced and either is a null pointer (because the pointed memory was zero-initialized) or has an indeterminate value if the expression `s + i` points outside the allocated memory.

You need to allocate an array of pointers of the type `char *` and assign to each pointer the address of an allocated array of characters.

Also in general you should check the return value of a call of `calloc` or `malloc`.

There is another problem with your code. After the call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%i", &n);  //number of strings being inputted
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that will be read by the following call of `fgets`. So the first call of `fgets` will read in fact an empty string.

Another problem is that you should remove the new line character that can be appended to the read string by `fgets`. For example some read string can contain the new .line character while others can be without it depending on how many characters the user typed.

If you want to write the program without using the subscript operator with pointers then it can look for example the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) == 1 )
    {
        scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
        scanf( "%*c" );
    }

    char **s = NULL; 
    
    if ( n != 0 ) s = calloc( n, sizeof( char * ) );
    
    if ( s != NULL )
    {
        size_t len = 11;
        
        size_t m = 0;
        
        while ( m < n && ( *( s + m ) = malloc( len  * sizeof( char ) ) ) != NULL ) m++;
        
        size_t i = 0;
        
        while ( i < m && fgets( *( s + i ), len, stdin ) != NULL ) i++;

        m = i;
        
        for ( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) //print the strings
        {
            ( *( s + i ) )[ strcspn( *( s + i ), "\n" )] = '\0';
            // or without the subscript operator
            // *( *( s + i ) + strcspn( *( s + i ), "\n" ) ) = '\0';

            puts( *( s + i ) );
        }
        
        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) free( *( s + i ) );
    }
    
    free( s );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
10
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%i", &n);  //number of strings being inputted
```

is incomplete, since [`scanf`(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) can fail (e.g. if your user enters `hello`). You need to add more code checking that `scanf` was successful. I suggest:

```
if (scanf("%i", &n) < 0) {
  perror("number of strings expected");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Then

```
char **s = calloc(n, 10 * (sizeof(char) + 1));
```

is wrong. Each element of the array is a `char*`, which on most machines has 4 or 8 bytes (the `sizeof(void*)`).

So replace it with

```
char **s = calloc(n, sizeof(char*));
```

or with the equivalent `char**s = calloc(n, sizeof(*s));` which in my opinion is less readable.

Also, `calloc` can fail. You need to add a test, like

```
if (s == NULL) {
   perror("calloc of s");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Read carefully the documentation of each function (like `calloc`, `fgets` etc...) which you did not wrote in [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

The next step should be a loop filling each element of `s`. With another `calloc`, or some call to [`strdup`(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) if your system provides it. Of course, that `calloc` (or `strdup`) can also fail and you need to test against failure.

You could also use [`getline`(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (or even [`readline`(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)) if your system has it. Check with your manager if you are legally and technically allowed to use them.

If your compiler is [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), invoke it with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Once you have no warnings, use a debugger like [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your executable.

Consider also using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) (after getting permission to use it).

Draw on  board (or on paper) a figure with arrows representing pointers (like the [doubly linked-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) figure on wikipedia) to understand the behavior of your program.

Comment: ^^^ especially since even with this change, `*(s+i)` is a null pointer, and `fgets(*(s + i), 10 * (sizeof(char) + 1), stdin);` is lying to `fgets`, telling it there is a buffer sized to 11 chars there.

Comment: I would suggest `char **s = calloc(n, sizeof(*s));`